# How I can delete queries "NULL" and "WKS" in DNS, bind9?

Tags: linux, bind

My problem is that through the desktop program "Your Freedom" are browsing the dns.

My DNS server has iptables, isolated on a server with ubuntu server 10.04.4.

The logs are dns (query.log):

```
**IN ANY**

17-Mar-2013 00:46:09.948 client 192.168.5.35#63175: query: ems07.your-freedom.de IN ANY + (192.168.1.9)

**IN NULL**

17-Mar-2013 01:09:41.972 client 192.168.5.35#61993: query: cF.U3lL1bd3QrllYjXCBUT53dE5GmCV18qvsv7ZqXzm96K4aoF9EHnPw7x1xq6LbYu.UKLkXn9UdIV0LrAfe5m0RSrDSlS57oQlZ5ouMasvIYD8NPxWSX0dBk87KnyRUYw.RS1IYgcG25jRUst7sADK86a1gSbvXG6IPj8NOKHrJvkQzaQJUAAR1kXcUTr.s07.1yf.de IN NULL +E (192.168.1.9)
17-Mar-2013 01:09:42.255 client 192.168.5.35#61994: query: cF.UDmlC8KJRLtiZBBzapjRbkuTOGgBVi1GvwlXIPf6dxoYdsF9EHnPw7x1xq6LbYu.Uugjw3kSv1tvyzYV8ZDTOyEQ7EDBSzfbqAkkOsoU4GZXcjzcMkal15cQAR6MDqy.R6T9ThodZFYlUPhflwDHU9queHLMYezYWPX9tBjavp6VID4pYS3UpoLmIJj.s07.1yf.de IN NULL +E (192.168.1.9)
17-Mar-2013 01:09:42.370 client 192.168.5.35#61994: query: cF.UDmlC8KJRLtiZBBzapjRbkuTOGgBVi1GvwlXIPf6dxoYdsF9EHnPw7x1xq6LbYu.Uugjw3kSv1tvyzYV8ZDTOyEQ7EDBSzfbqAkkOsoU4GZXcjzcMkal15cQAR6MDqy.R6T9ThodZFYlUPhflwDHU9queHLMYezYWPX9tBjavp6VID4pYS3UpoLmIJj.s07.1yf.de IN NULL +E (192.168.1.9)


**IN WKS**

17-Mar-2013 00:51:25.581 client 192.168.5.35.#61646: query: aD.Dw6Frkm3B6M0DSqer4hsquc3ikieVVCwnFOPygtO.s07.1yf.de IN WKS +E (192.168.1.9)
17-Mar-2013 00:51:25.592 client 192.168.5.35#61651: query: aD.D10EGWGYiyd8Zk0j5dLxPr3DlkieVVCwnFOPygtO.s07.1yf.de IN WKS +E (192.168.1.9)
17-Mar-2013 00:52:53.997 client 192.168.5.35#61694: query: bU.UmW0ZpDeMopiCIrS3263my9jdVuTsjwWVNQgRFl4ANMb2JavJU0py0bG6RCkU4u.UnGuqzINLRihL183WKS4w743SsdWYoyUTN9LSVCP9bYMkLdAJbt07QK4DvXfPLh.g4IPH2vOfb.s07.1yf.de IN NULL +E (192.168.1.9)
17-Mar-2013 01:04:22.474 client 192.168.5.35#61934: query: test.s07.1yf.de IN WKS +E (192.168.1.9)
17-Mar-2013 01:07:41.281 client 192.168.5.35#61956: query: test.s07.1yf.de IN WKS +E (192.168.1.9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No at the current **Bind** state of art.

See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/488949/bind9-how-stop-to-answer-specific-queries) answer for more information.